# How to toggle between 2 monitors in the 3rd monitor

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have 3 monitors - 2 of them are 23" PC monitors, and the 3rd is a TV monitor. They're all connected to the same PC, but the TV is placed in another room.

Right now, I duplicate my main PC monitor, on the TV, so sometimes I can work in the TV's room, and see all my open programs and stuff.. But as of right now I can't really access those applications that are opened on my second PC monitor... it's even worse when sometimes, when I'm working with the TV, and I open a window, it opens up in my second PC monitor, and it makes me go to the PC room and drag that window back to the TV\The other PC monitor...

So my question is: Is it possible with the help of some software, or maybe something built into Windows, to quickly switch the TV between the 2 PC monitors?
I'm not talking about changing the settings in the Display settings of windows.. this takes time, and it happens very often.. I don't want to toggle (with all the blinking and stuff..) the screens like that, but maybe use some software that will be always opened (minimized) in the main monitor, which will display the second monitor whenever needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can try [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/).

It does support many features.

1. efficiently move windows and maximize windows across the desktop
2. manage more applications with the Smart Taskbar control application
3. positioning with UltraMon Shortcuts

Comment: I must be honest and say that I've been using UltraMon for long time (few years), but I only used the smart task-bar feature (which duplicates the task-bar in all screens - something that is not supported in Windows < 8). I never checked the other features of this amazing software. This screen mirroring feature is so much awesome! I really does solve my problem! kudos to you for opening my eyes!